# How can I find the metadata of a file in Scanner app?

Tags: iphone, metadata, scanning

I am a teacher, and I am trying to verify the date and time when a student took a particular photo. The student has an iPhone (unknown model and OS version) and used the [Scanner app by Luni](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/scanner/id1291962681) to take the photo. The student says they can't find the date and time on their own, and I am not able to gain direct access to the student's phone due to covid-19 restrictions (the teaching is being done remotely).

I don't have (and have never used) an iPhone, but I assume that if the photo still exists on the phone there is a way to recover the metadata. Could someone point me towards a step-by-step tutorial for how to find a file's metadata either in this particular app or in whatever file manager iOS has built in?

To be clear the student is entirely cooperative, but seems to not be very technically knowledgeable (or even comfortable with technology), and my total inexperience with iPhones renders me unable to provide detailed, specific instructions. I have tried finding an iPhone emulator I can run on Windows, but I can't seem to find one which is free (or freemium) where I can easily see how to get to the app store.

**Edit:** If I get instructions for how to find metadata in a file manager, I will also need instructions for how to determine through the app what the location of the file is.

Comment: This app seems to create PDFs, is this correct?

Comment: I believe it "scans" by taking photos and then exports to PDF, yes. The photo is retained until deleted, but if it is stored as a PDF that would work instead.

Comment: The scan seems to be stored within the app only. There doesn't seem to be a way to access its timestamp there (if exported the timestamp of the exported file is the date/time of the export)

Answer (score 0):

In the App they can go to their scans, go to the export button at the top right, and click on iCloud. Then you can [run this shortcut](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/27a5b0693dac4d579f075e951545ffce) on their phone. If they haven't already they will need to [enable untrusted shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/enable-shared-shortcuts-apdfeb05586f/4.0/ios/14.0#apdf9081945c) (i.e. third party shortcuts).

Instead of using the shortcut, you could open the Files app, and go to *iCloud Drive > ScanPlus*. Hold down with your finger on the document to open the context menu, and select "Info". Under the heading "Information" you should see the creation date.